# Prove that there is not any integer $b$ such that when its initial digit is deleted , the integer becomes $ b/35 $

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

Prove that there is no integer b such that when its initial digit is deleted, the integer becomes $ b/35 $?

Comment: What about 135?

Comment: Or 17? Or 25? Or 81?

Comment: Do you mean $\frac b{35}$ instead of $b\mid 35$? Those are quite different; one is a number, the other is a statement.

Comment: There is an implicit assumption that the integers are expressed in base $10$ which ought to be stated. Supplementary question: what is the lowest positive integer base for which this becomes possible?

Answer (score 7):

Let $b$ be $10^nx+y$, where $x \in \{1,2,\ldots,9\}$. Deleting the first digit, we obtain $y = b/35$. This means we have
$$b = 10^n x+ b/35 \implies 34b = 35 \times 10^n x \implies 17 \vert x$$
which is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that when you delete the first digit it becomes $b/35$ then:
Take $b=a_1 a_2 \dots a_n $ where the $a_i $ are digits
If $a_2 a_3 \dots a_n  = b/35$ this is equivalent to:
$35*(a_2 a_3 \dots a_n)=b=a_1 a_2 \dots a_n $ 
Name $c=(a_2 a_3 \dots a_n) $ and it
means that $b=(a_1 *10^n) +c=(35*c)$ and then $(a_1*10^n)=34c$ then $17|a_1 *5^n$ and it is absurd because $a_i \in \{0,1, \dots ,9 \}$ and $5^n$ is only divided by powers of $ 5$ and $1$, then $b $ can't exist.

Comment: I think you ought to have $b= (a_1\cdot 10^n) +c$ instead of $b= (a_1\cdot 10^n) \cdot c$

Comment: Yes, thanks for the correction, I will edit that.